# Tkinter PIR sensor

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, motion-detection

I'm trying to create a smart mirror that displays different information such as the weather, 3 day forecast, news feed, and a tweet. I have all of this information printing in a window arranged how I want, but the final piece of the program I need to get to function with the rest of the program is a PIR sensor.

I have tested the sensor and it works by itself, but I can't think of a way to have the window be created, and then afterwards have the sensor start scanning for data to essentially turn the monitor on or off based upon if there is a person within range.

Like I said, I have all of the code functioning other than the fact I can't seem to figure out a way to get the tkinter window displayed and then afterwards have the program start scanning for motion to turn the monitor on and off. At this point I do not need the information (weather, twitter etc) to update, I am only worried about getting the monitor to turn on and off, or just black out and re-display the previously pulled information when a person is in range.

I have an example of what I have been using to change the state of the monitor at the beginning, because that is the last place I tried to place it before I decided to seek help.

From what I have gained from working with it is that it seems when the mainloop portion of the program is called it is not able to call other functions. I could be wrong, but this is how it seems.

I've thinned the program down to just the window functionality that I want. So with the code provided below I need to implement the PIR sensor to toggle the display on and off, after creating the display.

```
from tkinter import *
import os, subprocess
from gpiozero import *

pir = MotionSensor (4) 

while True:
if pir.motion_detected:
    subprocess.call('xset dpms force on', shell=True)
    print("yes")
else:
     subprocess.call('xset dpms force off', shell=True)
     print("no")






    #creates a fullscreen window and makes it black. 

       tk = Tk()
       tk.configure(bg='black')
       tk.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


       tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: I recommend cutting that example down as much as possible -- that's a lot of code to wade through. For example, do you really need the `toggle_fullscreen` and `end_fullscreen` functions for this specific question?  Do you really need all of those labels and images? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have thinned the code down to be easier to sift through.

Comment: Does `pir.motion_detected` block or take a long time to run, or is it fairly instantaneous?

Comment: pir.motion_detected is quick but a better way would be to use the pir.when_motion callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a tkinter program with an infinate while loop and expect the tkinter mainloop to run.

Suggest that you make use of the callbacks in gpiozero to call a function to enable the screen when motion is detected and perhaps a tkinter.after method to turn the screen off after a specified time period.

```
def myScreenOnFunction():
    subprocess.call('xset dpms force on', shell=True)
    print("Screen On")

....

pir = MotionSensor (4)
pir.when_motion = myScreenOnFunction

tk = Tk()
tk.configure(bg='black')
tk.attributes('-fullscreen', True)


tk.mainloop()
```

Something like this should play nicely with Tkinter and allow the main loop to run.

Comment: So an example I could use for the tkinter callback could be like the `.after` callback? When I use this I would call a function to disable the display after a certain period of time, but would I need to re-call the `.when_motion` or will it just keep looking indefinitely?

Comment: The function set to `.when_motion` will be called when ever motion is detected until the program ends. 
Yes you could use `.after` to call the function after a specified period.